# HTML element not displaying what debugger says it should

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, debugging

I'm building site using Twitter bootstrap and want to apply a background image to an `<li>` element when it is active in the navbar. I couldn't get the background image to display so as a test, I tried setting it a random background-color. What I found is that the debugger says that this background color (red) is applied to the element but on the actual page, it is clearly not red.
[image: Notice that the attributes the debugger displays do not show on the actual page]

Notice that the attributes the debugger displays do not show on the actual page. Why doesn't the `<li>` element have a red background?

I included only the relevant HTML

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>...</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">
    <script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/js"></script>
    <script src="./js/global.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/global.css">
  </head>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">

<div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.html">SMTHN</a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 1px;">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="./index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="./index.html">Tracks</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="./index.html">Merchandise</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a href="./index.html">Forums</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signInModal">Sign in</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUpModal">Sign Up</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-inverse {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.5px #9d9d9d;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.5px #9d9d9d;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.5px #9d9d9d;
}

li.active {
    background-color: red !important;
    background-image: url('../Images/button_glow.png');
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: i see it's working https://jsfiddle.net/9r39211z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems working fine. However I suggest you to use background for `a` instead of `li` since the hover is applied on `a` and if you use the active style for `li`, hover style will override it.

```
li.active > a {
  background-color: red !important;
  background-image: url('../Images/button_glow.png');
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8ENq.png notice this is the one taking style but you mentioned the active style only for `li.active` so bootstrap style override it.

here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tvrkezby/2/)

Comment: I really want the image to apply to the whole `li`, not just the `a` tag which is taking as little space as possible. Maybe I could force the `a` to take up all the space in the `li`?

Comment: did you check the fiddle? it is taking the whole `li` because `a` is already block. https://jsfiddle.net/9r39211z/2/ check this fiddle where i have applied image as well.

Comment: @Gaboik1 can you give link to your site, so that i can check what you missed. this minimal code that you've posted should work correctly. seems something else is wrong

Comment: oh my bad I did check the fiddle but for some reason I didn't realize the anchor tag took up the whole space. Unfortunately I don't have any web server on which to host the site at the moment so I can't really give you a link to it... Would you like for me to provide the whole code then?

Comment: @Gaboik1 yes, please provide the whole code in a form of fiddle here so i can take  a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141786/discussion-between-lucian-and-gaboik1).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your screenshot correctly, there's also a background image applied to the li so that's why you aren't seeing red.

The problem with your image not showing is likely a path issue, remember that the path is relative to your CSS file.

Use web inspector, check for errors and you'll probably be able to find the path that the browser is expecting to find the image and this should help you.

Good luck

Comment: I removed the `background-image` property and it's still not turning red. I am also certain that my relative path to my image file is correct. Could it be due to bootstrap somehow overriding my stylesheet even though it's called after bootstrap stylesheets and the  `i!mportant` clause?